# Rails 4 Nested form has_many through association and database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

So I have the three models client, address and address_info. When I create a nested form for address and address_info however I get basically double the rows that I meant to give it. The first three rows will have the addresstype and clientid tied to it and the other three will have clientid and addressid tied to it. Here is an example of the output:
[image]

As you can see, the rows do not have both the address and the client id's associated with the row. I'm not sure how to fix that.

Here are my models:

```
#client model
has_many :address_infos
has_many :addresses, through: :address_infos
accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses, :address_infos, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

#addressinfo model
belongs_to :client
belongs_to :address

#address model
has_many :address_infos
has_many :clients, through: :address_infos
```

Here is my clients controller:

```
def new
    @client = Client.new
    @client.address_infos.build
    @client.addresses.build
end
def create
    @client = Client.new(client_params)
end
private
    def client_params
        params.require(:client).permit(:firstname, :middlename, :lastname, 
        addresses_attributes: [:street, :city, :state, :zipcode], 
        address_infos_attributes: [:ownorrent, :addresstype, :yearsofresidency])
    end
end
```

Here is my view, note that there are also nested forms for a mailing and former address that I did not include:

```
 <%= form_for(@client) do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :addresses do |addresses_form| %>
        <!-- misc. code -->
    <%= f.fields_for :address_infos do |addressinfo_form| %> 
        <%= addressinfo_form.label :ownorrent, "Own", :value => "Own" %>
        <%= addressinfo_form.radio_button :ownorrent, :own %>                       
        <%= addressinfo_form.label :ownorrent, "Rent", :value => "Rent" %>
        <%= addressinfo_form.radio_button :ownorrent, :rent %>
        <%= addressinfo_form.text_field :yearsofresidency, class:"form-control", id:"inputfield", placeholder:"Years" %>
        <%= addressinfo_form.text_field :addresstype,:value => "presentaddress" %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**UPDATE**
So after doing what was suggested, I end up with this in my database:
The address I tried to add was for 123 Fake St. The other things were seeded directly. The address_id still does not stick with the rest of the stuff. I also updated my current models.
[image: Updated db]

Answer (score 0):

You should control nested attributes before saving in DB. Use `reject_if` or `allow_blank` options to prevent and destroy blank records.

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses, :address_infos, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

For more options to control the params, visits the link http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is that all that was wrong with the code? I didn't control the nested attributes yet since I wanted to see if I could get anything to push there at all.

Comment: Just try above solutions in your model. It will control nested attribute and will solve your problem. Thanks

Comment: You should use validates_associated to validate associated_records.